# Django field required in a clean method in a form class

Tags: django, forms, required-field

I want to redefine the required attribute for a field in a clean method of my form file:

```
class NewUserFullForm(NewUserForm):

REGEX_PHONE = '^(\+[0-9]{2})[ \.\-]?[0-9][ \.\-]?[0-9]{2}[ \.\-]?[0-9]{2}[ \.\-]?[0-9]{2}[ \.\-]?[0-9]{2}$'

phone = forms.RegexField(REGEX_PHONE, help_text='Ex : +33 1 34 12 52 30')
fax = forms.RegexField(REGEX_PHONE, help_text='Ex : +33 1 34 12 52 30',  required=False)
gsm = forms.RegexField(REGEX_PHONE, help_text='Ex : +33 6 34 12 52 30',  required=False)

def clean(self):
   if self.cleaned_data["asso_waldec"] == True:
      self.fields['phone'].required = True
```

But my clean method doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey! Have you looked at htis document/examples:

[Django Validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Maybe this will clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the clean function has to return the full collection of cleaned data (see [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)).  Rather than changing the 'required' attribute I believe you should do the check to see if 'phone' is blank and raise a 'ValidationError' describing the problem.

Also since your form inherits from 'NewUserForm' you should call 
`super(NewUserFullForm, self).clean()` to ensure that the inherited fields are cleaned as well.